# How to map API response to output claims in B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have use Technical Profile in B2C custom policy to call REST API and it returned format like this

```
{
   "value": [
      {
        "id":"00000000000"
        "name": "",
       }
    ]
}
```

So in case how to get id and map it to output claim ? Please let me know a way to do it, I have investigated but I can not find out a solution so far

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimfromjson

You want to extract `value.0.id`

Here you can see example json:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/blob/main/claims-transformation/json/CT_GetClaimFromJson.xml